# Choropleth in Python, with a twist

Tags: python, choropleth, world-map

I'm looking for a way to do a choropleth-style map in Python, but instead of shading the countries as a whole, I want to shade just the borders, including coastlines.
[Here's an image of a good example of what I am visualizing.](http://i154.photobucket.com/albums/s277/atombomb88/vlcsnap-7259428.png). My goal is to color the countries individually, not just the continents, but I'll settle for starting with the continents :)

I tried a few Python mapping packages and can't seem to get it to work. Normal choropleth maps are trivial, but restricting to just the borders seems impossible. Basemap has individually addressable country borders, but the coastlines are not included. And I am unaware of any other mapping libraries that allow changing the color of the borders.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What libraries are you using to generate the choropleth maps that do work?

Comment: [Basemap](http://ramiro.org/notebook/basemap-choropleth/) makes it pretty simple to create a choropleth. [Vincent](http://wrobstory.github.io/2013/04/python-maps-choropleth.html) as well